# gRPC Node microservice talking to another microservice in istio mesh

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio, grpc-node, istio-sidecar

I've got several gRPC microservices deployed via Istio in my k8s pod behind a gateway that handles the routing for web clients.  Things work great when I need to send an RPC from client (browser) to any of these services.

I'm now at the point where I want to call service A from service B directly.  How do I go about doing that?

Code for how both the servers are instantiated:

```
  const server = new grpc.Server();
  server.addService(MyService, new MyServiceImpl());
  server.bindAsync(`0.0.0.0:${PORT_A}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => {
    server.start();
  });
```

A Service Account is being used with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and a secret in my deployment YAML.

To call service A from service B, I was thinking the code in service B would look something like:

```
    const serviceAClient: MyServiceClient = new MyServiceClient(`0.0.0.0:${PORT_A}`, creds);
    const req = new SomeRpcRequest()...;
    serviceAClient.someRpc(req, (err: grpc.ServiceError, response: SomeRpcResponse) => {
      // yay!
    });
```

Is that naive?  One thing I'm not sure about is the creds that I need to pass when instantiating the client.  I get complaints that I need to pass ChannelCredentials, but every mechanism I've tried to create those creds has not worked.

Another thing I'm realizing is that 0.0.0.0 can't be correct because each service is in its own container paired with a sidecar proxy... so how do I route RPCs properly and attach proper creds?

I'm trying to construct the creds this way:

```
let callCreds = grpc.CallCredentials.createFromGoogleCredential(myOauthClient);
let channelCreds = grpc.ChannelCredentials.createSsl().compose(callCreds);
const serviceAClient = new MyServiceClient(`0.0.0.0:${PORT_A}`, channcelCreds);
```

and I'm mysteriously getting the following error stack:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Channel credentials must be a ChannelCredentials object
    at new ChannelImplementation (/bish/proto/activities/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:69:19)
    at new Client (/bish/proto/activities/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:58:36)
    at new ServiceClientImpl (/bish/proto/activities/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:58:5)
    at PresenceService.<anonymous> (/bish/src/servers/presence/dist/presence.js:348:44)
    at step (/bish/src/servers/presence/dist/presence.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/bish/src/servers/presence/dist/presence.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/bish/src/servers/presence/dist/presence.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Which is odd because channelCreds is a ComposedChannelCredentialsImpl which, in fact, extends ChannelCredentials

Answer (score 1):

Ok, at least the root cause of the "Channel credentials must be a ChannelCredentials object" error is now known.  I'm developing node packages side-by-side as symlinks and each of the dependencies has their own copy of grpc-js in it.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7742#issuecomment-257186653